# Multiple Definition error caused by Atmel Studio 6 linker

Tags: c, avr, atmel

I am having an issue with Atmel Studio 6.1 where I can not compile due to multiple definition errors, this seems to be caused by the linker duplication "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o" Does anyone know why it might be doing this? Below is a listing of the compiler output.

```
    Task "RunCompilerTask"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe all 
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.o" "../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.c
    Building file: ../Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.d" -MT"Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.o"   -o "Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.o" "../Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.c"
    Finished building: ../Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.c
    Building file: .././main_can_bootloader_example.c
    Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I".." -I"../Libraries" -I"../Libraries/lib_board" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/can" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom" -I"../Libraries/lib_mcu/flash" -I"../Libraries/lib_module/isp"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=at90can128 -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "main_can_bootloader_example.d" -MT"main_can_bootloader_example.d" -MT"main_can_bootloader_example.o"   -o "main_can_bootloader_example.o" ".././main_can_bootloader_example.c"
    Finished building: .././main_can_bootloader_example.c
    Building target: CAN-Bootloader.elf
    Invoking: AVR/GNU Linker : 3.4.2
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.2.939\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe" -o CAN-Bootloader.elf  Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_drv.o Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o Libraries/lib_mcu/can/reduced_can_lib.o Libraries/lib_mcu/eeprom/eeprom_lib.o Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_drv.o Libraries/lib_mcu/flash/flash_boot_lib.o Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.o Libraries/lib_module/isp/isp_lib.o main_can_bootloader_example.o   -Wl,-Map="CAN-Bootloader.map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mrelax -Wl,-section-start=.text=0x1e000  -mmcu=at90can128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker has `Libraries/lib_mcu/can/can_isp_protocol.o` two times on its command line. Linking fails, because of duplicate definitions.

As I am not using Atmel Studio 6, I cannot describe the exact steps to remove the duplicate.

1. You have possibly added `can_isp_protocol.c` two times to the project. Check your list of files in the project. Check your linker settings in your project options.
2. It probably turns up twice as well in the (generated/manually created) `Makefile`: Search for `OBJECTS` or `OBJS` (generally speaking search for `can_isp_protocol`, without extension), it could look like this:

> OBJECTS = can_isp_protocol.o can_isp_protocol.o x.o y.o

Comment: For my build (Atmel 7) this error was caused by redundant inclusion of `startup_samd10.c` and `system_samd10.c` in the Device_Startup folder.